# Edit head scripts in custom BigCommerce Stencil theme

Tags: templates, bigcommerce

I recently switched a client over from an old Blueprint theme to Stencil. Everything works great on my local environment, but after applying the theme on the live site, I've run into issues with scripts in the `<head>`. It's pulling in a custom script that was built for the former theme.

How do I access and purge these old scripts?

I presume the scripts are coming through `{{{head.scripts}}}` in my template file, but I can't find anywhere in the Stencil docs where this template var is mentioned.

Comment: That should be a variable that is supplied from BC's core app. Do you know what the script is?

Comment: It's a script written by the former developer on the former theme. It's definitely our own custom code, not BigCommerce's.

Comment: That was my bad! I forgot it also includes scripts that can be edited with the control panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Looks like the former developer hacked it in under **Advanced -> Web Analytics -> Google Analytics**.

I was also told that developers sometimes hide code in **Advanced -> Affiliate Conversion Tracking**.

Neither of these seem like good practices, especially when BigCommerce allows users to input custom footer scripts in **Storefront Design -> Design Options -> Scripts**.

Comment: Google Analytics is best if you need the script on every page including checkout, otherwise footer scripts is ideal as you can get some additional functionality with handlebars.